# angular-ui select2 tagging update the data value

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2

So this is my select2 input

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="ProjectTagpr" class="input-large" ui-select2="tagOptions" />
```

where in `tagOptions` is

```
{
    data: [{"id":301,"text":"tag2"},{"id":302,"text":"tag2"},{"id":303,"text":"tag3"},{"id":304,"text":"tag4"}],
    multiple: true,
    createSearchChoice: function(term) {
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        return {id: timestamp, text: term, new: true};
    }
}
```

and `ProjectTagpr` is

```
[301, 304];
```

which renders select2 with tags `tag1, tag4` **and turns** `ProjectTagpr` to

```
[{"id":301,"text":"tag2"},{"id":304,"text":"tag4"}]
```

**Now the first question**
Can I make it so it keeps the original `ProjectTagpr` structure(just an array of ids, instead of object with both id and text)?

**And the second question**
If I add a new tag, say `newtag5`, it would expand `ProjectTagpr` with something like `{id: 1554894854, text: 'newtag5', new: true}`, now when I press save and I'd like my $http to update the original `data` on the select2, so it adds the newtag5 there(of course returned with id from database and without that `new: true`), how would I do this?

I tried to do `$scope.tagOptions.data = dataReturnedFromHttp;` but that obviously(or not) didn't work..

Comment: So far I only managed to do it by destroying the select2() and reinitializing it with updated options.. which sucks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually fairly simple

```
data: function() {
   return {'results': $scope.data};
}
```

then it's pretty much live-binded.

It's just that it's somehow undocumented, that you can pass data a function..