# select2 tags with restangular response

Tags: angularjs, tags, restangular, angularjs-select2

How would I pass tags to select2 if the object comes from restfull API using restangular

So I have the following markup

```
<input type="hidden" ui-select2="select2Options" style="width:100%" ng-model="list_of_string">
```

returned restangular data

```
[
{"count":"13","brand":"2DIRECT GMBH"},
{"count":"12","brand":"3M DEUTSCHLAND GMBH"},
{"count":"1","brand":"a-rival"}
]
```

and here is my Controller method

```
var filterProducts = function($scope, api) {
   api.categories().then(function(response) {
        //this is the respose what I would like to use in select2 tags
        $scope.brands = response;
    });

    $scope.list_of_string = ['tag1', 'tag2']
    $scope.select2Options = {
        'multiple': true,
        'simple_tags': true,
        'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4']  // Can be empty list.
    };

};
```

Update

**Finally I managed**

and the hole looks like

```
$scope.select2Options = {
    data: function() {
        api.categories().then(function(response) {
            $scope.data = response;
        });

        return {'results': $scope.data};
    },
    'multiple': true,
    formatResult: function(data) {

        return data.text;
    },
    formatSelection: function(data) {
        return data.text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filterProducts = function($scope, api) {
   api.categories().then(function(response) {
        //this is the respose what I would like to use in select2 tags
        $scope.brands = response;
        $scope.select2Options.tags = response;

    });
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: Checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680336/angular-ui-select2-tagging-update-the-data-value